# A jquery function to decrease font size each time a button is pressed

Tags: html, jquery, css

Please help.

```js
function fontDown() {
  var curSize = parseInt($('.box').css('font-size'));
  curSize--;
  $('.box').css('font-size', curSize + "pt").css('line-height', curSize + "pt");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fontDown()">button</button>
    
<div class="box" style="font-size: 14pt; line-height: 14pt;">sometext</div>
```

I expect the font-size to decrease each time I press the button.  But, it only increases.  Not only that but the font size increases by about 5 or 7 points each time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a px to pt unit conversion.

The px to pt ratio is 4/3, so you get a bigger value in px unit, even if you decrease it by one. Then you assign this largest value with a pt unit, which produces a largest font size each time.

```js
function fontDown()
  {
  let curSize = Math.round( (parseFloat($('.box').css('font-size')) *3) / 4); 
                // px to pt converssion
  curSize--;
  $('.box').css('font-size', curSize + "pt").css('line-height', curSize + "pt");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fontDown()">button</button>

<div class="box" style="font-size: 14pt; line-height: 14pt;">sometext</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

use this:
it easy

operators `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, `/=` should be used in jquery

```js
function fontDown() {
  $('.box')
    .css('font-size', '-=1pt')
    .css('line-height', '-=1pt');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fontDown()">button</button>
    
<div class="box" style="font-size: 14pt; line-height: 14pt;">sometext</div>
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this answer, however, the pt value caused a problem and this function did not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

`.css('font-size')` returns a string like `18.6667px` which is a `px` value not `pt`.

Changing your code to use `px` instead will reduce the size as desired.

```js
function fontDown() {
  var curSize = parseInt($('.box').css('font-size'));
  curSize--;
  $('.box').css('font-size', curSize + "px").css('line-height', curSize + "px");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fontDown()">button</button>

<div class="box" style="font-size: 14pt; line-height: 14pt;">sometext</div>
```

Comment: This was also an answer but I wanted to keep pt font size because I am making a doc for print.  Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: I thought that I wanted to keep font sizes pt but what I realized is that once the text gets displayed on a browser page, it has already been converted to px.  pt values are important for css/print but for managing things with javascript, converting to px in the script is important.  It was hard to wrap my mind around that.